# How to extact elements from dictionary of lists efficiently?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my initial dictionary:

```
dic = {'key1': [2,3],
       'key2': [5,1],
       'key3': [6,8]}
```

*NB: I am using simple numbers 2,3, etc. for the purpose of the example (list of dfs on my side).*

For each key, I would like to extract the first element and obtain the following result:

```
dic2 = {'key1': 2,
        'key2': 5,
        'key3': 6}
```

**Is it possible to do it without going for a slow for loop ?** The dictionary is quite large...

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you think for-loops are slow? What *other* alternative would you have other than looping over the dictionary in some fashion or other??!

Comment: "The dictionary is quite large" how large?

Comment: If you expect to access only a few keys of the dictionary after this conversion, you could write a function that returns the first element only and use that instead of calling `dic2.get(...)`.

Comment: Or, indeed, a wrapper

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga arround 12k keys containing 12k stats dataframes.

Comment: @plonfat that's tiny. Looping over 12k keys and creating a copy manually with a loop takes less than a millisecond.

Answer (score 5):

If you expect to access only a few keys of the dictionary after this conversion, you could write a wrapper; something like:

```
class ViewFirst:
  def __init__(self, original):
    self.original = original
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.original[key][0]
```

Another option is to base it on `defaultdict`; that will let you do things like assigning new values into the dictionary (new or existing keys) while still retrieving other values from the original dictionary:

```
class DictFromFirsts(collections.defaultdict):
  def __init__(self, original):
    self.original = original
  def __missing__(self, key):
    return self.original[key][0]
```

---

**Edit:** Per the discussion in the comments, this is rather a special-purpose approach, for a specific scenario. For general-purpose use, prefer one of the approaches in the other answers, such as [U12-Forward's dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69298188/683329) `{k: v[0] for k, v in dic.items()}`; it's clear and straightforward, which is usually the more important concern.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to make your answer work.

Comment: It works specifically for the use case where you expect to access only a few keys, which you get from somewhere else; you can go `vf = ViewFirst(dic); print(vf['key1'])`

Comment: and why would i want to use that instead of `dic['key1'][0]` ?

Comment: Presumably you need to pass it to something that expects a dictionary (but isn't going to iterate over it, or at least not all of it); you implement just enough of the dictionary interface for it to work

Comment: There are situations where these sorts of wrappers are very useful; in this question, shorn of context, it's just a way of answering "how to do this without a loop". Note that if you're not looping over the whole thing, you're presumably just picking out some items, based on a short-list of keys coming from elsewhere. This answer would work even if the original dictionary is itself some sort of wrapper, perhaps for a key-value store or other disk or network access, potentially larger than memory, or even completely infinite (generated on the fly)

Comment: Yeah, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69292985/16759116) an example for a wrapper/proxy/adapter that I wrote just yesterday, providing a view into an m*n matrix because the search function works only on one-dimensional data and because it'll only access log(mn) elements (so building a list of all mn elements would be too costly). Also @MarcoD.G.

Answer (score 4):

A dictionary comprehension is the way to go here:

```
{k: v[0] for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Or use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> dict(zip(dic, map(itemgetter(0), dic.values())))
{'key1': 2, 'key2': 5, 'key3': 6}
>>>
```

Comment: note, this is still using a for-loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Edited with `map`.

Comment: Yea, that still basically uses a for-loop, just one underneath the interpreter level. It's note going to be much faster than a regular loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I guess operator.itemgetter will be the fastest option here ?

Comment: @plonfat Similar speed! dictionary comprehensions are also fast!

Comment: @plonfat they will all take a similar amount of time, similar to an equivalent for-loop. List comprehensions and map **are not for performance**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `for` loop even *wins* in my benchmark answer :-)

Comment: Me and @don'ttalkjustcode have done the tests and for a 12k-elements dict where the inner array has len > 2, the first solution you proposed is the fastest.

Comment: @MarcoD.G. Did you include the `for k, v in dic.items(): dic2[k] = v[0]` one?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode no, for n-array test i use yours `for k, (dic2[k], *_) ` which was the most interesting, the one you mention is identical to U12 first answer, so it performs exactly the same.

Comment: This (the dictionary comprehension) is the best general-purpose solution: clear, straightforward, maintainable. The vast majority of the time, those are  going to be vastly more important than shaving a millisecond off the runtime

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would go with a library that does that using Cython under the hood: [**cytoolz**](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/)

```
pip3 install cytoolz
```

```
from cytoolz import valmap , first

dic = {'key1': [2,3],
       'key2': [5,1],
       'key3': [6,8]}


dic2 = valmap(first, dic)
```

---

## Which is the best solution ?

I will extend @don'ttalkjustcode tests with my function benchmark, I'm still trying to figure out how to test the one by @Jiří Baum.

### General Case (n elements array) : @U12-Forward solution n° 1

using @don'ttalkjustcode generalized code `for k, (dic2[k], *_)`

3-elements dict:

```
    457 ns      457 ns      467 ns  U12_Forward_1
    775 ns      775 ns      776 ns  U12_Forward_2
   1021 ns     1021 ns     1036 ns  user1740577
    430 ns      430 ns      432 ns  Marco_DG
    679 ns      679 ns      683 ns  dont_talk_just_code
```

12k-elements dict:

```
 992967 ns   997872 ns   998554 ns  U12_Forward_1
1251728 ns  1254163 ns  1254897 ns  U12_Forward_2
1434998 ns  1436245 ns  1440789 ns  user1740577
1219357 ns  1219453 ns  1225301 ns  Marco_DG
2208451 ns  2213086 ns  2214531 ns  dont_talk_just_code
```

### Special Case (2 elements array) : @don'ttalkjustcode solution

3-elements dict:

```
    422 ns      422 ns      422 ns  marco_dg
    462 ns      462 ns      462 ns  U12_Forward_1
    765 ns      766 ns      769 ns  U12_Forward_2
   1076 ns     1081 ns     1088 ns  user1740577
    341 ns      341 ns      341 ns  dont_talk_just_code
```

12k-elements dict:

```
1206537 ns  1208705 ns  1211105 ns  marco_dg
1009374 ns  1011324 ns  1011989 ns  U12_Forward_1
1232356 ns  1232728 ns  1251990 ns  U12_Forward_2
1380953 ns  1382381 ns  1390140 ns  user1740577
 848863 ns   850010 ns   850450 ns  dont_talk_just_code
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's see how "slow" a for loop really is here. My solution:

```
dic2 = {}
for k, (dic2[k], _) in dic.items():
    pass
```

Benchmark with your toy dict:

```
    600 ns      602 ns      603 ns  U12_Forward_1
   1019 ns     1025 ns     1027 ns  U12_Forward_2
   1347 ns     1350 ns     1355 ns  user1740577
    441 ns      442 ns      443 ns  dont_talk_just_code
```

Benchmark with a "large" dict of 12k items as you commented:

```
1412624 ns  1414927 ns  1418089 ns  U12_Forward_1
1687464 ns  1690134 ns  1696759 ns  U12_Forward_2
1961205 ns  1986729 ns  2005884 ns  user1740577
1248901 ns  1260306 ns  1261295 ns  dont_talk_just_code
```

The above were done [on tio.run](https://tio.run/##fVNNb9swDL37V/BSRA6ELLbbpQuQ6/7BTkEgqDbTarFlQ6KzdUF@e6YPu4nbojwEpkk@vvfMdK/00urisTOXy960DZBqUBGopmsNgcEOJSWhsu91SW1b27HYSUNK1rHadmgktWYsKsLmGYnQJEmFe/iV5eJna/5IU4mMVapM1wm4MEi90XA6rOG4Xe5g7yAOHI6gNLiuhcexLD1/RMk/orgXxP6pzlc4NLJjVxpsmfKAeJR1jw7SRQTtLZpsdb98WK2@hlwc8NUN8lpZYuHHF@ZTUCfiDblqNQmS9UH87i2Jsq3wZoN7ymEDp3PIBuG@nm8POw4ifedBnPLRSWvfkcyTxH8g6wAnVvOpZ/xWLf@MYGT@hLp8iTbqvnlCM2zHvx2W5JaEZU5r0PMmwL/1rEP1yteg7etx6joRpBiliY0Nm2EBD50LIbRsUIjYHludteM24VcZqZ@RFTfufEHEB3mPrLtRrFi8bzZcMvPd4UjSUfZmUJ9u18VuAhPZzNnsblWBtjCDO2AE34ZBmEOGP9JAhjwTsumnqibKou2nmTu0bLaGbc4Ldwk@zX36wLMhLXz6nT/uzhyypY90HN77@kmdfYfi93n8T6mrV1nu291g4YYul/8), which I use for its high speed and speed stability. Sadly it doesn't offer `cytoolz` needed by Marco's answer, so I couldn't include that. Then @user1740577  accused me of lying because I didn't include it, so here are results from replit.com, where I can (note that if you run it there and don't have a paid account, your times will be slower):

```
    475 ns      476 ns      484 ns  U12_Forward_1
    804 ns      805 ns      807 ns  U12_Forward_2
   1075 ns     1079 ns     1082 ns  user1740577
    442 ns      444 ns      448 ns  Marco_DG
    360 ns      360 ns      360 ns  dont_talk_just_code

1060461 ns  1061449 ns  1071588 ns  U12_Forward_1
1294079 ns  1330157 ns  1706065 ns  U12_Forward_2
1593082 ns  1594114 ns  1596703 ns  user1740577
1268663 ns  1274264 ns  1286715 ns  Marco_DG
 964445 ns   965971 ns   966333 ns  dont_talk_just_code
```

Full benchmark code (also [at replit](https://replit.com/@dtjc/so-69298180-dict-with-v0):

```
from timeit import repeat
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter
from cytoolz import valmap , first

def U12_Forward_1(dic):
    return {k: v[0] for k, v in dic.items()}

def U12_Forward_2(dic):
    return dict(zip(dic, map(itemgetter(0), dic.values())))

def user1740577(dic):
    return dict(zip(dic.keys(),list(list(zip(*dic.values()))[0])))

def Marco_DG(dic):
    return valmap(first, dic)

def dont_talk_just_code(dic):
    dic2 = {}
    for k, (dic2[k], _) in dic.items():
        pass
    return dic2

funcs = U12_Forward_1, U12_Forward_2, user1740577, Marco_DG, dont_talk_just_code

def bench(dic, number):
    expect = funcs[0](dic)
    for func in funcs:
        result = func(dic)
        print(result == expect, func.__name__)
    print()

    for _ in range(3):
        for func in funcs:
            ts = sorted(repeat(partial(func, dic), number=number))[:3]
            print(*('%7d ns ' % (t / number * 1e9) for t in ts), func.__name__)
        print()

bench({'key1': [2,3], 'key2': [5,1], 'key3': [6,8]}, 100000)
bench({f'key{i}': [i,42] for i in range(12000)}, 30)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237469/discussion-on-answer-by-dont-talk-just-code-how-to-extact-elements-from-diction).

Comment: How does that loop work? Why does `dic2[k]` assign the first element to that key in that loop statement? Since we normally have to say `dic2[k] = foo`.

Comment: @KarlWilhelm [That's just how assignments work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69220399/16759116) in Python. It's a target in the for-loop's target list, so it gets assigned. From Python's perspective that's nothing unusual, really. It's just unusual in the sense that somehow most people chose a detour with a variable like your `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
dict(zip(dic.keys(),list(list(zip(*dic.values()))[0])))
```

Output:

```
{'key1': 2, 'key2': 5, 'key3': 6}
```

Comment: Great idea ! Would this solution be faster than the ones proposed above ?