# How to add new keys and value of each of them in python with list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list.
I want to add a new key to the dictionary so that the value of each of them is equal to one of the array elements. I have explained more about this in the example below

my dictionary

```
[{'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-1', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 1},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-2', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 2},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-3', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 3}
]
```

my list

```
['a','b','c']
```

What I want:

```
[{'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-1', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 1 , 'content' ='a'},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-2', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 2,  'content' ='b'},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-3', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 3,  'content' ='c'}
]
```

Comment: OK, so what's the problem?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can not solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Seems pretty straightforward. Loop over the lists, and add the key to the corresponding dictionary...

Comment: That's not a dictionary, that's a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip to pair up the dictionaries withe the content strings and set the 'content' key for each:

```
dicList = [{'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-1', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 1},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-2', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 2},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-3', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 3}
]
contents = ['a','b','c']
for d,c in zip(dicList,contents):
    d['content'] = c

print(dicList)

[{'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-1', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 1, 'content': 'a'}, 
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-2', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 2, 'content': 'b'}, 
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-3', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 3, 'content': 'c'}]
```

Or, if you want the result in a new list, you can use a list comprehension to build augmented dictionaries:

```
dicList2 = [{**d, 'content':c} for d,c in zip(dicList,contents)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip and assign:

```
for d, d['content'] in zip(dicts, contents):
    pass
```

Demo ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBCoNADETv@YrcUmFbUS9F6JcUD3ZVXNDdsJsWbPHbrVZ7FQMhEGYezPAgrbPZlf00mZ6dF2T2xgpAZbQEvOH9Q0/fUY7UinDI41jqIBft@rgxtoq1keGckEISI4tsPl39e7zKxZeMCvAIJN2BpEch2Q4kG6EA7azUdo1GJSl6zKupAGicx0phdadNQwUai2/Dp18ZCv/eKAech8sQANbCLrypomn6Ag)):

```
import pprint

dicts = [{'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-1', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 1},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-2', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 2},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-3', 'tit': 'title1', 'val': 3}
]
contents = ['a','b','c']

for d, d['content'] in zip(dicts, contents):
    pass

pprint.pp(dicts)
```

Output:

```
[{'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-1',
  'tit': 'title1',
  'val': 1,
  'content': 'a'},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-2',
  'tit': 'title1',
  'val': 2,
  'content': 'b'},
 {'url': 'https://test.com/find/city-3',
  'tit': 'title1',
  'val': 3,
  'content': 'c'}]
```

Comment: Interesting implementiation! I never knew you could do that! +1

Comment: @Jab Yeah, seems many people don't know. I've been doing it for a long time and have rarely ever seen anyone else doing it. [Some benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69244531/16759116).